# Conditional formatting not correctly colouring cells with a "0" value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this to establish an average in cell I6.

`=IFERROR('Governance Crib Sheet'!C9*100,"0")`

And then this to colour the result:

[image]

If the average comes out at 0, it stays green when it should be red.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Any chance this is a conflict between the numeric value 0 and the string value "0"?

Comment: change `"0"` to `0` as @CarlManaster explained.  `"0"` returns a string and is therefore greater than any number.

Comment: He shoots he scores! Thanks both. Carl if you can answer the question I'll mark you up! @CarlManaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conflict between the numeric value 0 and the string value "0".

Here's how to fix it:

```
=IFERROR('Governance Crib Sheet'!C9*100,0)
```